# Why isn't std::optional<T>::value() a free function?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, option-type, member-functions

As I know, it is recommended to use non-friend non-member functions when possible as it decouples algorithms working with the class from its private fields. Using this logic, we would probably implement `std::optional<T>::value()` as something like

```
template<typename T> T& value(std::optional<T>& optional) {
  if (optional.has_value()) {
    return *optional;
  } else {
    throw std::bad_optional_access("empty optional");
  }
}
```

However, `value()` is a member function. Why? Same question can be applied to `std::optional<T>::value_or()`.

Comment: it is also recommended to encapsulate and provide semantically sound APIs. What would you rather have? `optional.value()` or `std::value_of_optional(optional)`

Comment: If that is the case, we can implement `std::vector::empty` based on `std::vector::size()` and as a non-member class, no?

Comment: @Gupta theoretically speaking, some collections can have O(N) `size()` so it is not a good example, I suppose. However, `cbegin()` or `crend()` etc. probably could be generalized free functions, couldn't they?

Comment: @passing_through They already are free functions. The free functions are only (as far as I know) used because we would like them to work with arrays which cannot have member functions. For class types, the free functions simply call the member function by same name.

Comment: @eerorika really. I actually don't even see reasons to make member `c`-versions of `begin()` and `end()`. Are there any?

Comment: @passing_through Of course. Every standard container has the c-prefixed begin and end iterator accessors.

Comment: @eerorika I mean - are there any reasons to provide such functions as members instead of one general `auto cbegin(T const& container) { return container.begin(); }`?

Comment: @passing_through Yes, see Geoffroy's comment.

Comment: @passing_through: Also, Container.begin() dates back to the original STL, before C++'98. I'd have to search for dates, but it might even predate Koenig lookup which is necessary to make `begin(vec)` work.

Comment: @passing_through: "*theoretically speaking, some collections can have O(N) size() so it is not a good example*" No, the presence of a `size` member is a declaration that this operation is O(1). You can always get the size from `std::distance(c.begin(), c.end())`.